# forecasting with future/advanced booking data

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I am looking for a method that incorporates historical data and future incomplete data. I have historical demand data (container usage at a rail yard) that I can use to predict future demand. However, I also have future container booking/reservation data that customers placed in advance. This data may change in the future as some customers may cancel their reservation or some customer may add to the existing reservation.
Is there any method that can be used to combine both predictions using time series and the available incomplete booking data?